# Postgres how to keep the newest copy based on a column and delete older records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a fact table keep getting large amount of records inserted. It is for ML prediction results for original records in another table. Since the frequency of inserts is very high, I want to keep only the prediction results for last batch before insert the results from a new batch. How do I write a query to delete older records while only keep the latest copy of every record_id?

```
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
| row_id | record_id | prediction | insert_ts  |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
|      1 |       101 | cat        | 2020-06-04 |
|      2 |       102 | dog        | 2020-06-04 |
|      3 |       103 | tiger      | 2020-06-04 |
|      4 |       101 | tiger      | 2020-06-05 |
|      5 |       102 | lion       | 2020-06-05 |
|      6 |       101 | dog        | 2020-06-06 |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

After I run the query the following should be what's left in the table.

```
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
| row_id | record_id | prediction | insert_ts  |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
|      3 |       103 | tiger      | 2020-06-04 |
|      5 |       102 | lion       | 2020-06-05 |
|      6 |       101 | dog        | 2020-06-06 |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I found some post suggest truncate the table and insert back the newest records. But that would mess up the row_id which is `serial` and serves as foreign key reference in other tables. How do I write this `delete` query?

Comment: why don't you create a new table.

Comment: @zealous how do I keep the old row_id for the records left and also the sequence nextval of row_id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get latest record by using `row_number()`. You can create a new table with following query which will only have latest date records.

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sri17vJHK48UG19LJ3chmD/0).

```
select
   row_id,
   record_id,
   prediction,
   insert_ts
from
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by record_id order by insert_ts desc) as rnk
  from myTable
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Output:

```
| row_id | record_id | prediction | insert_ts  |
| ------ | --------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 3      | 103       | tiger      | 2020-06-04 |
| 5      | 102       | lion       | 2020-06-05 |
| 6      | 101       | dog        | 2020-06-06 |
```

You can also handle this logic in your code as well, where new update on existing `record_id` comes then delete the old one and insert the new one or overwrite it.

Comment: How do I create a table when another table with the same name exists?

Comment: @ddd did you try the above solution? and you mean same name of the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
with keep_these as
(
 select distinct first_value(row_id)
   over (partition by record_id order by insert_ts desc) as rid 
 from tbl
) 
delete from tbl where row_id not in (select rid from keep_these);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the fate of a record depends on the existance of other records, you can use `EXISTS()` :

---

```
DELETE FROM the_table d
WHERE EXISTS (                      -- a record exists
    SELECT * FROM the_table x
    WHERE x.record_id = d.record_id -- with the same record_id
    AND x.insert_ts  > d.insert_ts  -- but with a newer timestamp
    );
```